# Restricting by resource ownership in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Using Spring Data REST, I have a many-to-many relationship:

- User entity class with a set of Task:

  `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

  private Set<TaskRecord> tasks;`
- Task entity class a set of User:

  `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})

  @JoinTable(name = "task_user")

  private Set<User> users;`
- A table (`task_user`) that connects the two (via two columns, `task_id` and `user_id`)

I want to restrict operations such that a user can only access a task if the user is an owner of it (i.e., there is an entry in `task_user` for that task id with that user id).

I am currently achieving that for POST and PUT via `@HandleBeforeCreate` and `@HandleBeforeSave` event handlers. Is there a way to achieve this for any and all operations using `@PreAuthorize` or something else?

Comment: Sure; Use `Repository` as base class for your own repositories and add `findOne`, `findAll` and `save` methods with `@PreAuthorize` annotations on there, and it should all just work. You can even use the principal in your `@Query` methods if you use `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` as per the docs. Have you tried any of that already?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have tried. I'm aware those exist, what I don't know is how to a) properly form them (e.g., within pre-authorize, how do I do the check for "does this TaskRecord contain the requesting user in its set of User?) and b) whether, for example, if I have to use @Query that the trade off (in writing the SQL) is worth what is lost (e.g., easy ability to swap between data store implementations because of JPA).